# Multiline tooltip doesn't work programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

`&#13;` is supposed to separate lines on tooltip hover.

This doesn't work:

```
var doesntwork = document.getElementById("doesntwork")
doesntwork.title = "line1&#13;asdfa";
```

But doing it in the html works:

```
<div title="line1&#13;asdfas" id='works'>
</div>
```

See an example of this here, just hover on the squares:

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/3yg535jq/

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `doesntwork.title = "line1\nasdfa` works. My guess is that HTML code actually converts `&#13;` to `\n` when rendering while JS just shows it as it is part of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into this issue all the time.  For some reason xml special chars work fine when entered into the xml but not when they are added via javascript.  It is very annoying

I am not sure if it is a solution you can use, but instead of using  you could use \n

```
doesntwork.title = "line1\nasdfa";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like this: `doesntwork.title = "line1\r\nasdfa";`

`/r` for carriage return.
`/n` for newline

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/3yg535jq/4/

Answer (score 0):

I found this little solution I came up with humorous if nothing else.

https://jsfiddle.net/1fp7frer/

```js
var doesntwork = document.getElementById("doesntwork")
doesntwork.title = "line1&#13;asdfas".replace(/&#(\d+);/g, String.fromCharCode);
```

```css
#works {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}

#doesntwork {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div title="line1&#13;asdfas" id='works'></div>
<br/>
<div id='doesntwork'></div>
```